# Build doc2vec model and find textually similar reviews using gensim

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, similarity

The dataset is Amazon's review dataset in gz file.

```
# A function to read the zipped data at a specfic path
#
# How to use:
# PATH = "/path/to/file"
# for line in parse(PATH):
#   do something with line
#
def parse(path):
    g = gzip.open(path, 'r')
    for l in g:
        yield eval(l)
```

The following code is given.

```
import os
def read_reviewers_data(fname, min_count=0):
    '''
    Save all reviews into their own product asin files.
    Make sure you have 'product' folder when you run this answer.
    In each file, you can choose your own log structure. In this answer, log 
    strucutre is like 
        "reviewText"\t"reviewerID"\t"helpful"
    Args: 
        fname: dataset file path
        min_count: minimum number of reviews of a product
    Returns:
        none
    '''
    if not os.path.isdir('product'):
        os.makedirs('product')
    asin_list = []
    tmp_list = []
    last_asin = ""
    j = 0
    for i in parse(fname):
        if last_asin != i['asin']:
            if len(tmp_list) > min_count:
                f = open("product/" + last_asin+".txt", 'w')
                for one in tmp_list:
                    f.write(one)
                f.close()
            tmp_list = []
            last_asin = i['asin']
        tmp_list.append(i["reviewText"] + '\t' + i["reviewerID"] +
                    '\t' + handle_helpful(i["helpful"]) + "\n")
        j += 1
        if j > 100000:
            break
            
def handle_helpful(helpful):
    '''
    Helper function for helpful_score calculate
    Args: 
        helpful: list. The first element is the number of people think this is helpful. The second element
            is the total number of people evaluate this comment
    Returns:
        String: number represent helpfulness
    '''
    if helpful[1] != 0:
        helpfulness = 1.0 * helpful[0] / helpful[1]
        return str(helpfulness)
    else:
        return str(0)
```

From my understanding, the above code creates a 'product' folder with txt files named after the asin code. For each txt it stores the review,the reviewer_ID and their helpfulness score.

```
read_reviewers_data("reviews_Electronics_5.json.gz")
```

```
class TaggedReviewDocument(object):
    '''
    This class could save all products and review information in its dictionary and generate iter for TaggedDocument
        which could used for Doc2Vec model
    '''
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname
        self.helpfulness = {}  # key:reviewerID value:helpfulness
        self.product = {}      # key:asin value:reviewerID
        self.asin = []

    def __iter__(self):
        for filename in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            asin_code = filename[:-4] #delete ".txt"
            self.product[asin_code] = []
            self.asin.append(asin_code)
            for line in enumerate(open(self.dirname + "/" + filename)):
                line_content = line[1].split("\t")
                self.product[asin_code].append(line_content[1])
                self.helpfulness[line_content[1]] = float(line_content[2])
                yield TaggedDocument(clean_line(line_content[0]), [line_content[1], line_content[2]])
```

```
documents = TaggedReviewDocument("product")
```

I'm a bit unsure of what does "TaggedReviewDocument" function do here.It seems to create a document with dictionary and key value.
The first task is to create a doc2Vec model. My code goes:

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument, Doc2Vec

model_v = Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=5, window=2, min_count=1, workers=4)
```

The second task is to find top 5 helpful reviews of the same product with similarity score above 0.8.I'm thinking similarity score is based on similarity of reviews(text) and then rank them by helpfulness score. However,I had completely no idea on how to call the most_similar argument in gensim.model using the above document.I had no idea on how to extract the text review from documents either.

```
def find_similar_reviews(asin,reviewer_id):
    '''
    If one review is similar to the specefic review and it is much helpful, save it to a list
    Args: 
        asin: product asin
        reviewer_id: the specific review
    Returns:
        list of reviewer id
        
    '''
    result = []
    #
    
    return result
```

I don't know which part of the document stores the text review.Any help will be appreciated.

And whatever I tried to output,it shows nothing in documents:

```
documents.product
```

output: {}

```
documents.helpfulness
```

output: {}

The dataset is taken from here:
http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon/productGraph/categoryFiles/

Named: 'reviews_Electronics_5.json.gz'

Comment: Have you examined what's inside the `documents` object after you've run the code you don't understand? Can you print any reviews – even, say, just one review? If you can do that you'll have found the review text & b ready to feed that text elsewhere.

Comment: (As a separate note, it's not really typical to use a model like `Doc2Vec` with merely 5-dimensional vectors. These models really only show their power with many-more dimensions – 100 or more is typical, though some toy demos can get away with 20+. A mere 5 dimensions is unlikely to do much that's interesting. And similarly, `min_count=1` is usually a mistake with this algorithm: it does better ignoring rare words than including them all, which is why the default is `min_count=5`.)

Comment: Hi,sorry I just saw your comments.I've edited the parameters to vector_size = 300 and min_count = 5.

Comment: 300 dimensions would only be appropriate with a lot of training text, and a large vocabulary. Do you know how much text you have? Have you examined what's in `documents`? Can you print the text of even just a single review?

Comment: No,whatever I tried in the documents,it always shows nothing...I've add it to the body of question

Comment: If the `documents` object is intended to be a corpus for training, then it needs to be a re-iterable sequence that has as each item one `TaggedDocument` (with both `.words` & `.tags` attributes). It doesn't make sense for it to have its own `.product` or `.helpfulness` attributes. (Those seem to be fields of individual reviews, **not** the whole set. But further: `Doc2Vec` doesn't work on such properties: only `.words` & `.tags`. So any code in your `TaggedReviewDocument` class assigning into things like `self.product` etc doesn't make sense: it's not putting data where relevant to `Doc2Vec`.

Comment: Do you know how much text you have? Can you examine what's actually given out by an iteration over the `documents` object - for example by examining what `next(iter(documents)` returns, to see what the 1st item in its sequence is? (If it's not a sensible `TaggedDocument` with intended words/tags, then you don't have an adequate corpus for training.)